# MySQL SQL - How to Query 2 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

table 1

```
uid    email          name        password
----------------------------------------------
1      abc@abc.com    John Doe    9q8wekdshfa
2      xyc@xyc.com    Jane Doe    a42adsflda2
3      me@meme.com    Meme Me     asd4q23llsd
```

table 2

```
id    uid    vocation       groups
-----------------------------------
1     1      Programmer     1,3,4,5
2     2      Designer       2,4,6,8
3     3      Attorney       3
```

How do I write the query to get all the data about the user/s that belongs to the same group as the active logged in person. Suppose that I'm logged in as the 3rd account (me@meme.com) and I already have the data that my group is 3. How do I write the query to get this result?

```
uid    email           name        password       vocation     groups
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1      abc@abc.com     John Doe    9q8wekdshfa    Programmer   1,3,4,5
```

Comment: you will need to join the tables.

Comment: Why do you take the time to write your post without doing any basic research and with no knowledge or attempts at what you want to achieve whatsoever? A couple of searches would have  been quicker yet you choose to waste all of our time?

Comment: Okay let me edit it. It's a little complicated for me that's why I posted it here.

Comment: @JBES i finished editing it

Comment: You missed the point, maybe correctly so, This is getting downvoted because it is a very basic question that has been answered a hundred times. Please familiarise yourself with the basics of MySQL and its JOINS - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html and use the search facilities to find many examples of what you require.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a basic join statement:

```
SELECT table1.uid, table1.email, table1.name, table1.password, 
table2.vocation, table2.groups FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON
table1.uid = table2.uid
WHERE table2.groups LIKE '%3%' AND email<>'me@meme.com'
```

And certainly read up on JOIN and basic SQL table relationships. This is database 101 stuff, that's the only reason you're getting a bit of grief in the comments and down votes.

Comment: i only need results from a specific group. in that example. i only need the users that are in group 3. (logged in account is excluded which is me@meme.com)